# VSFTPD installed, but I can't restart/stop it

Tags: server, vsftpd, drupal

I've installed VSFTPD on my VPS running Ubuntu server 10.04. When connecting using FTP clients such as Filezilla it's working perfectly. However when I use my Drupal's native FTP client to update the modules and the core installation my "working" login credentials are not working.

So after searching the internet, there are some configurations that should be changed on "vsftpd.conf" which I followed and those instructions say that I should restart my VSFTPD.

So after trying these commands

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
service vsftpd restart
```

Both results to *respectively

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/vsftpd: command not found
service vsftpd restart
```

Then there's another weird thing that went out when trying to find out the problem my self

When I type

ls -l /etc/init.d

It results to

```
.
.
.
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    21 Oct  2 06:29 vsftpd -> /lib/init/upstart-job
```

What could be wrong?

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue?? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I have also got this error in my lubuntu. I had to try the following sudo restart vsftpd

Comment: Use Command sudo service vsftpd restart

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Command `sudo service vsftpd restart`

you can see below i have done

```
sysadmin@localhost:~$ sudo service vsftpd restart
vsftpd stop/waiting
vsftpd start/running, process 21140
sysadmin@localhost:~$
```